# I simulated some dataset in excel for transportation problem.I useTransP package it gives me this error

Tags: r, excel, simulation

```
> nwc(rew)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
> rew
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  ...1      M1    M2    M3    M4 Supply
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 W1        20    22    17     4    120
2 W2        24    37     9     7     70
3 W3        32    37    20    15     50
4 Demand    60    40    30   110    240
>
```

I am working on simulated data in R. When I run one of the files using the nwc function in the TransP package in R, I get the error message. How can I resolve this?

I have over 100 files that I need a for loop to use the function nwc to call all files one after the other and provide the result. But this error does is not going away

Comment: Your first column has the name `..1` and is type `character`, and thus causing the error. Does that column have meaning for the analysis you're doing? If not, just drop the column.

Comment: Thanks a lot but the excel file has it as blank. dont know how to get drop the column.

Comment: M1 M2 M3 M4 Supply
W1 20 22 17 4 120
W2 24 37 9 7 70
W3 32 37 20 15 50
Demand 60 40 30 110 240

Comment: Have you considered the Solver in Excel?

Comment: @Solar, Solver in Excel can get the optimal solution, but I want to use R function as required by my supervisor.

Comment: to drop the column from the R dataframe you can just do `rew = rew[, -1]` (i.e. this selects all rows, and all columns *except* the first one).

Comment: @mikeck, thanks a lot. It worked. Nightmare gone for now.